# ggplot - adding subscript AND second row to x-axis tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, subscript

I am attempting to create x-axis tick mark labels than contain both subscripts along with a second row. I am able to create a second row as well as a single row with subscripts. However, I am unable to create both. Attempting to add “n\” to the label code(s) used results in errors.

In short, I want to create the first line of x axis tick mark labels with subscript added AND then add a second line to the tick mark labels.

The following code creates the data frame

```
    `
    n=50
    data <- function(ids) {
    obs.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(ids),Route=rbinom(n,1,.5),Cohort = sample(1:3, n, 
    replace=T),Cohorts = sample(4:6, n, replace=T), Result= runif(n, 25000, 75000))
    names(obs.data) <- c("ID","Sex","Cohort","Cohorts","Result")
    obs.data<-obs.data[order(obs.data$ID),]
    return(obs.data)
    }
    test<-data(ids=1:n)
    test$Cohorts<-ifelse(test$Cohorts==4,"Cohort 1, 2, 3",ifelse(test$Cohorts==5,"Cohort 2, 
    3","Cohort 3"))
    test$Parameter<-ifelse(test$Cohorts== "Cohort 1, 2, 3","X14",ifelse(test$Cohorts=="Cohort 2, 
    3","X43","X84"))
```

`

The following code creates the double lined tick labels i am desiring

`             AUClabels<-c("XYZ0-14\n Cohort 1, 2, 3",
             "XYZ0-43\n Cohort 2, 3" ,
             "XYZ0-84\n Cohort 3")

```
testp1<-ggplot(test, aes(x=as.factor(Parameter), y = Result), group=interaction(Cohort,Cohorts,Sex))+
geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Sex), fill=factor(Sex),shape=factor(Sex)),size=2.75)+
scale_x_discrete(labels = AUClabels)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 1))+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","black"))+
scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black"))+
scale_y_continuous(limit = c(20000, 80000))+
ggtitle("")+
ylab("")+
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
theme(legend.position="")+
theme(legend.title=element_blank())
testp1
```

`
   [image: Two lined X axis tick mark labels]

This code creates the subscript

'
    AUClabels2<-c(expression(XYZ[0-14]),expression(XYZ[0-43]), expression(XYZ[0-84]))

```
testp2<-ggplot(test, aes(x=as.factor(Parameter), y = Result), group=interaction(Cohort,Cohorts,Sex))+
geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Sex), fill=factor(Sex),shape=factor(Sex)),size=2.75)+
scale_x_discrete(labels = AUClabels2)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 1))+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","black"))+
scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black"))+
scale_y_continuous(limit = c(20000, 80000))+
ggtitle("")+
ylab("")+
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
theme(legend.position="")+
theme(legend.title=element_blank())
testp2
```

'
[image: Subscripted X axis tick mark label]

Comment: I think you might be looking for the `atop` function to make these patterns: `expression(atop(XYZ[0-14], "Cohort 1, 2, 3"))`

Comment: Exactly! Works perfectly.  Thank you